# Break a string and merge string in c# with show and hide options

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**My Requirement:**

My string should be break after some words and at place we need to place "+more" option. when user click the "+more" need to show entire text. after end of the text need to show "-hide". when user click the "-hide" then it should be show previous. means some text with "+more" option. can any one help this.

**my code:**

```
var fullString= "string with above 150 charecters here";
 var compressedString = TotalNews.fullString(150);
 <div class="Temphide">
   @compressedString
  </div>
<a class="show" id="@newsItem.ApplicationNewsId">+More</a>

var Continues = fullString.Substring(150, TotalNews.Length - 150);
<div style="display:none;" >
 @fullString &nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="hide">-Hide</a>
</div>
```

**script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.show').click(function () {
            $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
        });

        $('.hide').click(function () {
            $(this).parent().slideUp();
        });
    });

</script>
```

**My problem:**
Here when i click "+more" option i am showing  "+more" with "-hide". requirement is when click "+more" need to show fullstring with "-hide" option. but i am doing showing "+more"  and "-hide". please can any one help this.

Comment: @ Pankaj Garg: Thank you for post the answer. i have done this with help of http://jsfiddle.net/Pjgzq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Script:**

```
$.fn.truncate = function(options) {
    $(this).append('<span class="truncate_lh" style="display:none;">&nbsp;</span>')

    var defaults = {
        maxlines: 2,
        moreText: 'More',
        lessText: 'Less',
        ellipsis: '...'
    };

    $.extend(options, {
        lineheight: ($('.truncate_lh').css('height').replace('px', ''))
    });
    $.extend(options, {
        maxheight: (options.maxlines * options.lineheight)
    });
    options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        var text = $(this);

        if (text.height() > options.maxheight) {

            text.css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'height': options.maxheight + 'px'
            });

            var link = $('<a href="#" class="showHide">' + options.moreText + '</a>');
            var wrapDiv = $('<div class="truncate_wrap" />');

            text.wrap(wrapDiv);
            text.after(link);

            link.click(function() {
                if (link.text() == options.moreText) {
                    link.text(options.lessText);
                    text.css('height', 'auto');
                } else {
                    link.text(options.moreText);
                    text.css('height', options.maxheight + 'px');
                }
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
};

$().ready(function() {  
    $('.truncate').truncate( {  
        maxlines: 4
    });  
});
```

**View**

```
<p class="truncate">//Here text...</p>
```

I have done this with help of

http://jsfiddle.net/Pjgzq/1/

visit this link